# How to find candian postal code between low and High by SQL Server or c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, postal-code

I just want to know how to find Canada or UK postal between low and High Postal code.

For Example: *Low* postal code: `A0A0A0` and *High* is: `A0Z9Z9`

How to find postal code between these postal  `A0A0A0` and `A0Z9Z9`?

Comment: It would help if you provided some sample data and your expected output for us to work with.

Comment: You need regex or validation?

Comment: If it's so urgent perhaps you should respond to @RichBenner

Comment: @scsimon it was so urgent we haven't seen anything of OP for 2 hours.

Comment: Hey sorry for late reply, I have Candian postal code list that have high and low. Now I just want to find if anyone enter the postal that exist in postal code or not. The postal code must be also find between high and low.  Ie. Low High
                A0A1A0 A0J1V0   How to find postal code between A0A1A0  and A0J1V0

Comment: I have canda Extended area list. In the list i have low and high postal code. Now my question is how to check the postal code is enter by user is extended or not . Postal code must be find between low and high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [LIKE pattern matching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

```
WHERE Code LIKE 'A0[A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9]'
```

Answer (score 1):

MSSQL can do it from box. Let's say you have table where you have values:

```
A0A0A0
A0Z9Z9
A0A0A1
A0A0A2
A1A0A0
```

If you write query like this:

```
SELECT [name]
FROM [PostalCode]
WHERE name >= 'A0A0A0' AND name <= 'A0Z9Z9'
```

You get:

```
A0A0A0
A0Z9Z9
A0A0A1
A0A0A2
```

`name` field is `NVARCHAR` type.

Comment: I have canda Extended area list. In the list i have low and high postal code. Now my question is how to check the postal code is enter by user is extended or not . Postal code must be find between low and high.

Comment: @Shishant ask another question

Answer (score -1):

You can try to look for the correct Canadian postal code here http://worldpostalcode.com/canada/ . I always use this service, moreover, there are a lot of other countries. I hope I was useful. Take care

Comment: While your link is helpful to find codes, you can see OP has already said he has the list and want to find the codes from his Database.